# Issues with scipy interpolate griddata polar coordinates

Tags: python, matplotlib, interpolation, polar-coordinates

I have used scipy griddata to interpolate with polar data. I have a file with azimuth, altitude, and a value.

First, I converted azimuth and altitude to Cartesian coordinates to use with griddata. I then create steps from 0 to 90 for altitude and 0 to 360 for azimuth.

```
alt = np.array(alt)
x,y = alt * np.cos(az), alt*np.sin(az)
xi = np.linspace(0, 90, 100)
yi = np.linspace(np.radians(10.), np.radians(350.), 100)
zi = griddata((x, y), value, (xi[None,:], yi[:,None]), method='cubic')
ax = plt.subplot(111, projection='polar')
cm = plt.cm.get_cmap('jet_r')
levels = np.linspace(min(value),max(value), 100)
cf = plt.contourf(yi,90-xi,zi.T,levels=levels,cmap=cm)

cbar = plt.colorbar()
cbar.set_ticks(np.arange(15.5,22, .5))
cbar.set_label(r'mag/arcsec$^2$')
ax.set_theta_zero_location('N')
ax.set_theta_direction(-1)
ax.yaxis.grid(False)
#ax.set_rticks([])
ax.scatter(az,90-alt, marker='.', edgecolors='k', facecolors='none')
ax.xaxis.grid(False)
plt.ylim(0,90)

plt.show()
```

I cannot agree with what was returned for griddata. For example, the data point (the black dots) at 225 at the lowest altitude is 16.5 mags/arcsec^2. Griddata returned a value around 18.5 mag/arcsec^2 for that area. My other issue is how bad the interpolation is at azimuth 350-10. It does not blend well. See below:

[image]

I changed the range from 10 to 350 to get:

[image]

Which I am happier with, but I would like to fill in the keyhole in the plot.

Any help filling in the keyhole is greatly appreciated. As well as how to improve the griddata results.

I also do not agree with the polar plot rotation and data mapping. I believe there is some errors there, but that is for another post.

Comment: It doesn't look like there is anything wrong with the plot. If you want people to verify, you need to provide a [mcve].